# Wrap exist directive in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js in my application, and I have a form which contains a lot of fields:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="idname">Name:</label>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="idname" ng-model="name" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="idemail">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="idemail" ng-model="email" name="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="idtype">Choose Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="idtype" name="type">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

There are almost 60+ fileds, and most of the markups is bootstrap styles related, so I want to simplify the markups, like this:

```
<form>
    <input label="Name:" type="text" model="name">
    <input label="Email Address:" type="email" model="email">
    <select label="Choose Type:" model="type">
        ....
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to add some extra attributes like `label` and `model` for the form inputs, then I will generate the label and input element and wrap them with the bootstrap styles. Also I want the third directives like `min-length` or anything else still take effect.

I tried to create the directive like this:

```
  .directive('label', function() {
    return {
      priority:1,
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: "field.html",
      replace:true
    };
  })
```

However it does not work as expected, the custom-ed element like

```
<input label="Name:" type="text" model="name">
```

are not inserted into the template, and the label is not generated:

```
  <div class="form-group">
  </div>
```

I think the `compile` and `link` may be necessary, but I have no idea how to implement them.

This is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XPox6X00aqiFxqHgwaEB).

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: I update it, please have a check.

Answer (score 0):

Replace is deprecated since Angular 1.3.

But it works: https://jsfiddle.net/basslagter/yh0qdbhL/1/

What you can do (because of the deprecation) is make a custom element:

```
<custom-label label="Name:" type="text" model="name"></custom-label>
```

Defined as:

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
myApp.directive("customLabel", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<label>The label was: {{vm.label}}</label>',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        scope: { label: '@' },
        bindToController: true,
        controller: function(){}
    };
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/basslagter/yh0qdbhL/